# Converting a LINQ result to 2D string array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query that selects a list of teamIDs and team names to populate a drop down list. The query looks like this:

```
var teams = db.Teams.Where(t => t.isActive)
                    .Select(t => new {t.TeamID, t.TeamName});
```

However, I want the result set to be in the form of a 2D string array, since that's what my function that populates DDLs requires. I know I can use a for loop and build the array, but I'd prefer it, if possible to do it all in one step.

Is there something similar to this?

```
string[][] teams = db.Teams.Where(t => t.isActive)
                           .Select(t => new {t.TeamID, t.TeamName})
                           .To2DArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of:

```
string[][] teams = db.Teams.Where(t => t.isActive).Select(t => new[] {t.TeamID, t.TeamName}).ToArray();
```

Comment: You confused the anonymous object syntax, `new { a,b,c=c }` with the array initializer syntax `new[] {a,b,c}`.

Comment: Other direction. The question is making an anonymous type, but I think you read it as making an array.

Comment: @Strilanc Oh, that's my fix!

Answer (score 4):

Note that `string[][]` is not a multi-dimensional array, it's an array of arrays. Multidimensional arrays look like `string[,]`, and have different semantics (i.e. an array of arrays may have subarrays of differing lengths, but all rows/columns in a multidimensional array have the same length).

Since you're just dealing with arrays of arrays, the easiest solution is probably using ToArray on a sequence of items which are themselves created with ToArray.

The following code assumes that db.Teams is also an array of arrays:

```
var teams =
    db.Teams
    .Select(teamArray =>
        teamArray
        .Where(t => t.isActive)
        .Select(t => new {t.TeamID, t.TeamName})
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Off topic and I know you already know this, true "multidimensional" arrays (`string[,]`) in .NET are an abomination: slower to access, hard as hell to write generic methods to operate on (for an arbitrary # of dimensions at least), and under all sorts of one-off-ish arcane rules.